# Replace unicode value in string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unicode, str-replace

I have a string `@"\EOP"`. I want to dislpay this to user. But when i display this string in textfield, It shows only `OP`. I tried to print that in console while debugging and it shows `¿OP`

So `\E` is unicode value and that's why it's having some issue of encoding. I can fix this issue by:

```
NSString *str=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\E" withString:@"\\E"];
```

With this it will display perfect string `@"\EOP"`.

Here my issue is that there can be many more characters same like `\E` for example `\u`. How can I implement one fix for all these kind of characters?

Comment: Where does the string come from?

Comment: One Question : Why are you using the same name `str` ?

Comment: @MartinR string comes from database, but i checked with setting static string str=@"\EOP"; but still not worked.

Comment: @Vin I checked with both way with same string and with separate string but same result.

Comment: @OKNC2: Do you have `\u` in the string? Can you show an example?

Comment: @MartinR with the strings which i have, there are not any \u but there can be manay number of strings. so possibly there can have. so i want to replace if any.

Comment: @OKNC2: The question would be what "\u" stands for. My answer below tries to cover all known escape sequences for control characters, such as "\e", "\r", "\n", ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\E` in the string `@"\EOP"` is the character with the ASCII-code (or Unicode) 27,
which is a *control character*.

I don't know of a built-in method to escape all control characters in a string.
The following code uses `NSScanner` to locate the control characters, and replaces them
using a lookup-table. The control characters are replaced by "Character Escape Codes"
such as "\r" or "\n" if possible, otherwise by "\x" followed by the hex-code.

```
NSString *str = @"\EOP";

NSCharacterSet *controls = [NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet];
static char *replacements[] = {
    "0", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "\\a",
    "\\b", "\\t", "\\n", "\\v", "\\f", "\\r", NULL, NULL,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, "\\e"};

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];

while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    NSString *tmp;
    // Copy all non-control characters verbatim:
    if ([scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:controls intoString:&tmp]) {
        [result appendString:tmp];
    }
    if ([scanner isAtEnd])
        break;
    // Escape all control characters:
    if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:controls intoString:&tmp]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < [tmp length]; i++) {
            unichar c = [tmp characterAtIndex:i];
            char *r;
            if (c < sizeof(replacements)/sizeof(replacements[0])
                && (r = replacements[c]) != NULL) {
                // Replace by well-known character escape code:
                [result appendString:@(r)];
            } else {
                // Replace by \x<hexcode>:
                [result appendFormat:@"\\x%02x", c];
            }
        }
    }

}

NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Comment: Great, Yes this is working..One more question, does it make any change if i set \E instead of \e or can i set both in that replacements[]?

Comment: @OKNC2: It seems that NSString accepts both `\e` and `\E` for the same character 27. But for example `\N` does not work instead of `\n` for the newline character. Therefore I would just use the lowercase versions.

Comment: @MartinR. Hey need your help again please. I have posted new question.Need reverse process from this answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629634/string-with-escape-character

Answer (score 1):

You can always replace `\` with `\\`. These are called [Escape Sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15387756/1603072).

**Sample Code :**

```
NSString *str = @"\EOP";
NSString *myNewStr = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"];
NSLog(@"myNewStr :: %@",myNewStr);
```

Comment: Means its giving same string as before like ¿OP. tried with this way.  str=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"];

Comment: actually that line shows it will replace \ with \\. But as in Nsstring its not allowed to use \ we need to use \\ as i think.

Comment: It will never work, if you use this line in Xcode you can know that it will generate syntax error.

Comment: I tried this way already before post question but not worked. :(

Comment: This does not work. Note that the string `@"\EOP";` **does not contain any backslash character!** The first character of that string is U+0027 (the "Escape" character), which is escaped as `\E` in the input - confusing, I know! Therefore trying to replace backslashes with something else cannot work.

Comment: **Still this is not working!!** **Please re-ensure your self before posting.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want a backslash (`\`) to appear in a string literal, you need to escape it in the string literal i.e.

```
NSString* foo = @"\\EOP";
```

The above will give you the Unicode sequence 5C 45 4F 50 which is what you want.