# String includin Escape character

Tags: iphone, unicode, escaping

In textfield when user enter value with escape character, I want to work this same as user enter but it behaves like a string for \e too.

In more detail.
suppose user have entered \e[3~ but when i print it in console it shows \e[3~. Actually this should print like ¿[3~ so it will work perfect for me.

I have tried by this line and it works.

```
NSString * str=[textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\e" withString:@"\e"];
```

But suppose if user enter value in caps like \E[3~ then its not replacing. so i have tried with like

```
NSString * str=[textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\e" withString:@"\e"];
        str=[textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\E" withString:@"\E"];
```

But this is not working in case while user have entered text in small \e[3~. With this when first line will execute to replace \e it will give me perfect result like ¿[3~ but when it will execute next line it gives me same \e[3~ string.

Please suggest me how can i check for both letters and if i can check for all escaping characters at once.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564950/replace-unicode-value-in-string

Comment: @user1673099. Actually that's for reverse case. I want reverse things then that answer as described in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your code is that the second line takes the *original* string `textField.text`
instead of the result from the first line. What you probably meant is:

```
NSString *str = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\e" withString:@"\e"];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\E" withString:@"\E"];
```

Alternatively, you can do the replacement in a single step by using the
`NSCaseInsensitiveSearch` option:

```
NSString *str = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\e"
                        withString:@"\e"
                           options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [textField.text length])];
```

Comment: ohh yes my mistake.Working with above line. Thanks for reply. One more question Have you any idea if want to check for all escape char at once?

Comment: @OKNC2: Perhaps you can use the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313631/replacing-multiple-characters-in-nsstring-by-multiple-other-characters-using-a-d, which does multiple replacements using a lookup dictionary. Or you use NSRegularExpression to search for all escape sequences.